# CSS selector not changing link color

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My html and css files are set up correctly, however I'm having trouble with a certain selector.

I have the html here:

```
<span id="bottom_nav_bar"> 
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
</span>
```

And the CSS here:

```
a#bottom_nav_bar{ color: red; text-align: center; }
```

However, my span is not getting selected and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#bottom_nav_bar a{ color: red; text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 3):

It should instead be:

```
#bottom_bar_nav a {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

As the `<a>` is a descendant of the `<span>` with the ID `bottom_nav_bar`

Answer (score 3):

You're not targeting the `a` element. Your CSS selector is attempting to style an `a` element with an `id` of "bottom_nav_bar". In your HTML, however, the span has this ID and the anchor element is within the span.

To target the anchor tag, change your CSS selector to:

```css
#bottom_nav_bar a { color: red; text-align: center; }
```

To target just the span, change `a#bottom_nav_bar` to `span#bottom_nav_bar`.

For more information about selectors, please see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: Thank you very much I overlooked this

Answer (score 0):

use this to select the span link

```
span #bottom_nav_bar a{ color: red; text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link don't have this id, so it can't work...

Put your id to the a-tag ;)